# QML: Component vs Item as a container

Tags: qt, delegates, qml, qtquick2, qqmlcomponent

What is the difference between `Component` and `Item` in QML ? The documentation is not absolutely clear here. 
What is the preferred type to use as a container for several widgets?
Can it be replacable by `Rectangle`?

For example, what is the difference in the following declarations:

```
Item {
    id: itemWidget

    Rectangle { id: one }
    Rectangle { id: two }
}
```

and

```
Component {
    id: componentWidget

    Rectangle { id: one }
    Rectangle { id: two }
}
```

Why do we usually use `Component` when declaring a `delegate`?

Comment: What don't you understand about the docs? They can't be improved if you don't say why they aren't clear. I think that they are quite clear, and any answer you get here will most likely be a re-wording of what already exists.

Comment: I agree with @Mitch, the Qt documentation is the best docs I've ever seen so if you found that not clear I think you won't find any help here.

Comment: Added some example to the question description

Answer (score 19):

The difference between those two snippets is that the `Rectangle` will be immediately displayed. This is written in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#details):

> Notice that while a Rectangle by itself would be automatically rendered and displayed, this is not the case for the above rectangle because it is defined inside a Component. The component encapsulates the QML types within, as if they were defined in a separate QML file, and is not loaded until requested (in this case, by the two Loader objects). Because Component is not derived from Item, you cannot anchor anything to it.

When declaring delegates, `Component` is used because there are several delegate items that must be created. A single `Item` doesn't work here. You can think of `Component` as a template that you can create objects from.

Answer (score 5):

A `Component` is both a concept and a thing in QML.  An `Item` is a visual thing defined in QtQuick module which is usable in QML.  These two things are conceptually different.

As a QML concept, all reusable things are called components. You can define a component in multiple ways, but one easy way is to create a `.qml` file and name it as you name your component.  i.e: Button.qml or Switch.qml.  When the QML engine loads that file, you can use it as buttons or switches.

Another way to define a component is to use `Component {}` in a `.qml` file.  This allows you to define a new component *inline*.  A component defined *inline* does not work after explicitly loaded by a [loader](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html).

An `Item`, on the other hand, is a simple type defined in the QtQuick module.

I think it is OK to call an `Item` a `Component` even though an `Item` is not  technically inherited from `Component`.  Or more precisely, you could say your custom component is based on an `Item` if your `.qml` has `Item` as a root type.